# Sort List by a string column value as datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following list (myListOfRecords) that I want to sort by column0, which holds string values that represent date-times in the following format: `MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Column0 { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
}

IList<ViewModel> myListOfRecords
```

How can I sort that list by a string column value as datetime without changing types in my ViewModel?

Comment: Sort it before it gets sent to the  Viewmodel when they are still dates?

Comment: Why on earth are you using strings to hold DateTime values in the first place? Use DateTime and it's `ToString` method when you need to display it.

Comment: @Tony - my sorting conditions might change, so I don't think I can do that in advance.

Comment: @Patrick - typo. corrected.

Comment: @Zohar - my view model is shared and used for all sorts of data.

Comment: @Peter yes, you can sort in advance. LINQ's OrderBy accepts any delegate you pass to it. As long as you *don't* convert the DateTime to a string, you won't have to wonder about date formats.

Comment: @Peter in fact, it's *precisely* because the VM is used for many things that you *shouldn't* use inappropriate types. If the property names are `Column0` and `Column1` the VM is essentially useless. A Tuple would be better. A ViewModel is meant to provide the data used by *one* view, not reused to carry unrelated data

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create `DateTime.TryParseExact` to make your customer `DateTime` format in a function and return `Datetime`

```
static DateTime GetDate(string Column0) {
    DateTime dt;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Column0, "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt",
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        dt = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

then using linq `OrderBy` and use `GetDate` let `Column0` to `Datetime`

```
IList<ViewModel> myListOfRecords = new List<ViewModel>();

myListOfRecords.OrderBy(x => GetDate(x.Column0));
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3e4ex3)

**NOTE**

I would suggest you use `Datetime` instead of `string` save datetime value.